# C# Modification of IEnumerable mystery, what is modifying my IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, ienumerable

I've written an extension method to add items to an (EF) EntityCollection. I got an interesting error, saying that my collection of IEnumerable ("items") had been modified, after the first loop in the foreach. When I turn items into items.ToList() (like in the code below), it works fine.

I completely understand that doing ToList() will produce a copy of the items on which the foreach will then operate.

What I do NOT understand is what is modifying the IEnumerable when I'm doing a foreach over it.

Update: Somehow, it seems the items variable is the same as the collections variable?

Update 2: **I think collection and entity may be affected by EF's entity tracking, but I still fail to understand why**

Usage:

`ssp.ServiceAreas.ReplaceCollection(model.ServiceAreas);`

Here's my extension method:

```
    public static void AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(this EntityCollection<TEntity> collection, IEnumerable<TEntity> items)
        where TEntity : EntityObject, IProjectIdentity<int>, new()
    {
        foreach (var item in items.ToList())
            collection.AddOrUpdate(item);
    }

    public static void AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(this EntityCollection<TEntity> collection, TEntity item)
        where TEntity : EntityObject, IProjectIdentity<int>, new()
    {
        if (item.ID > 0 && collection.Any(c => c.ID == item.ID))
            collection.Remove(collection.First(c => c.ID == item.ID));
        // For now, the Remove NEVER gets hit

        collection.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: `Remove` modifies it, so does add.

Comment: @vcsjones Although that is true, in this situation it isn't that simple.

Comment: Is `items == collection` in your case ?

Comment: You are adding/removing items from the collection you're foreach-ing through (1st method calls the 2nd one for each item in the foreach block, and the 2nd one is ading/removing things).

Comment: First: How is "items" the same as "collection"? Second: The remove actually never gets hit, I'll update the post.

Comment: @sebastiaan If the remove never gets hit but `collection` == `items`, the `Add` will cause issues.

Answer (score 4):

```
collection.Remove(collection.First(c => c.ID == item.ID));
```

you are removing in the collection you are iterating.

Comment: but the iteration is through a different collection (items)

Comment: Indeed I upvoted this but on trying it, this doesn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following sample code:

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var one = new List<string> {"Adam", "John"};

            var two = new List<string> {"Adam", "Houldsworth"};

            one.AddOrUpdate(two);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static void AddOrUpdate(this IList<string> collection, IEnumerable<string> items)
        {
            foreach (var item in items.ToList())
                collection.AddOrUpdate2(item);
        }

        public static void AddOrUpdate2(this IList<string> collection, string item)
        {
            if (collection.Any(c => c == item))
                collection.Remove(collection.First(c => c == item));

            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

This works as you would expect, there are no errors. So in essence, none of the lines are causing issues.

What will cause issues is if you call the list on itself:

```
one.AddOrUpdate(one);
```

So from what I can see, you must be calling this extension method with the same collection as both arguments.

If you are, then both `Remove` or `Add` will mutate the collection and cause this exception.

Comment: Thanks, but this works with and without the .ToList() .. simply because collections and items are indeed different object. I think my collection object may be affected by EF's tracking mechanism, will update posts again. :-)

Comment: @sebastiaan Yeah I noticed it worked without `ToList` also, but I was keeping it similar to your provided code to demonstrate where the issue was coming in.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `EntityCollection` doesn't like when someone takes over it's elements? So, when you Add to `collection`, item gets Removed from `items`.

Or it could be that `items == collection`

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the first item is always a new item, and thus by default the ID is set to some initial value. It will then be added to the collection, letting the EntityFramework generate a new ID and assign it to the first added item.

It then might be that the EntityCollection thinks it has changed, because it uses the ID to sort or do something else internally. And thus the foreach operation (which is probably using the same list) throws the exception. That's also why the test-case proved by Adam Houldsworth does not give the issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
EntityCollection<Customer> customers = new EntityCollection<Customer>();
Customer newCustomer = new Customer() {ID = 0};
customers.Add(newCustomer);
customers.AddOrUpdate(customers);
```